# How do I do http get and post requests in Wicket 7.x?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wicket, wicket-7

I am using Wicket 7.x in an Eclipse IDE Maven Project (the Quickstart project from the Wicket website) and deploying it on a localhost Tomcat server. Basically I want to send HTTP GET and POST requests to a specified URL (a REST service) in order to create a simple CRUD for my Java2EE framework homework. I mostly work with AngularJS and there you just need to use one command:

```
$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
$http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Are there any structures that perform similarly in wicket? I have seen some jQuery AJAX examples, but none of them seemed to fully explain how to make the request (input the URL etc). So if you have any ideas, please throw them my way. All of this just seems so needlessly complicated. Also if this was easier in any previous versions, I can probably downgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no opportunity to perform this operations via Wicket's tools I suppose.
Try to use [Apache's HttpClient library](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html).

Comment: This is correct! Apache Wicket doesn't have APIs for such things. You could use HttpUrlConnection, Apache HttpClient, Retrofit, Feign, OkHttp, and many more.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but yes it did work. Generally anything that allows you to do post/get requests in Java will work.